# C# inheritance and interface implementation question: why is the output a zero?

Tags: c#, inheritance

The output is a zero, unless B explicitly implements interface ITest, which seems redundant:

```
class B: A, ITest
```

Code:

```
   interface ITest
    {
        int AProperty { get; }
    }

    class A : ITest
    {
        public int AProperty { get => 0; }
    }

    class B : A
    {
        public new int AProperty { get => 1; }
    }

    class Program
    {

        static void Process(ITest test) 
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Value: {test.AProperty}");
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var b = new B();
            Process(b);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
```

If the property gets reintroduced in B (**new** int AProperty) or not makes no difference. Why?

Interestingly, when I debug this and look at the test variable in the immediate window, this is how it looks:

```
test
{ConsoleApp3.B}
    AProperty (ConsoleApp3.A): 0
    AProperty: 1
```

Which means that an instance of class B has 2 different properties named AProperty

Comment: You're not overriding the existing property.  You're hiding it, which means it's only seen when you deal with a `B` type variable.  Once it's cast to `ITest` it will find the implementation in `A` which is not `virtual` and use it.

Comment: "B explicitly implements interface ITest" No, it does not. It creates a complete independent definition for the member that is in no way related to the interface.

Comment: The fact that you have to write `new` is a giveaway: the reintroduced property on `B` makes no difference at all to how `ITest.AProperty` is implemented on `B`. Make the property `virtual` in `A` and you can override it in `B`.

Comment: @juharr Even if the member was `virtual`, the interface has no knowledge of it and thus the hiding member won´t be called.

Comment: @HimBromBeere I'm just saying that since it's not virtual it's not going to look any further.  If it where it would require `B` to use `override` instead of `new` to actual use the `B` implementation.